# Ansible create a dictionary from list where odds are keys evens are values

Tags: ansible

I have data in YAML format below

```yaml
ospf_neighbors:
  - data: xe-0/0/1.0
  - data: Full
  - data: xe-0/0/10.0
  - data: Full
  - data: xe-0/0/11.0
  - data: Full
```

What I want to do is create a dictionary with basically the odds been keys and the evens been values. This is the target:

```yaml
ospf_neighbors_dict:
  xe-0/0/1.0: Full
  xe-0/0/10.0: Full
  xe-0/0/11.0: Full
```

```yaml
- name: Create Dict Pair for OSPF neighbors
  set_fact:
     ospfneighbors_dict: "{{ ospfneighbors_dict|
                             default({})|
                             combine({item['data'][::2]: item['data'][1::2]}) }}"
  with_items: "{{ ospf_neighbors }}"
```

But that is just splicing the data, e.g "Fl": "ul"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of solutions, one:

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ospf_neighbors_dict: "{{ ospf_neighbors_dict|d({})|
                                 combine({ospf_neighbors[item].data:
                                          ospf_neighbors[item + 1].data}) }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, ospf_neighbors|length, 2) }}"
```

Result:

```yaml
ospf_neighbors_dict:
  xe-0/0/1.0: Full
  xe-0/0/10.0: Full
  xe-0/0/11.0: Full
```

Comment: Wouldn't t you mind simplifying the code? It's easier to see the options, I think. But, feel free to revert it. FYI, the callback *yaml* is easier to read.

Comment: @VladimirBotka, no revert, you have right.!! its better...

Comment: Thanks i had to do one small update as i was getting the following error "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: xrange(0, 6, 2)"  So i added | list to loop:  so the loop is like this loop: "{{ range(0, ospf_neighbors|length, 2)|list}}" seems to work great thanks

Answer (score 2):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ospf_neighbors_dict: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(_vals)) }}"
      vars:
        _data: "{{ ospf_neighbors|map(attribute='data')|list }}"
        _keys: "{{ _data[::2] }}"
        _vals: "{{ _data[1::2] }}"
```

creates the target

```yaml
ospf_neighbors_dict:
  xe-0/0/1.0: Full
  xe-0/0/10.0: Full
  xe-0/0/11.0: Full
```